# Getting javascript array from django json dumped dictionary

Tags: javascript, json, django

I have a `json-dump` data from `Django` view -

> {"7": {"1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "11": 1, "12": 0}}

I need an array in `javascript` from the `json` data like -

```
var list = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Also I need the key "7". No `jQuery` but `javascript`

Here is so far I tried -

```
var json_data = JSON.parse({{ vote_records }});
    json_data.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry);
    });
```

What is the best way?

Comment: Please give us a [mcve] to show your efforts

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qcL9dg79/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map all sorted keys for the values.

```js
var object = { 7: { 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0, 10: 0, 11: 1, 12: 0 } },
    key = Object.keys(object)[0],
    keys = Object.keys(object[key]),
    array = keys.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; }).map(function (k) { return object[key][k]; });

console.log('key', key);
console.log('array', array);
```

Comment: You just managed to sneak that in ;) - but why sorted?

Comment: because objects have no order, so i assume, the keys are the indicator for the position.

Comment: Hmm, Ok, good idea, I am wondering however if there are any JS implementations that would not return the values in order?

Comment: i dont know. it depends on the creation order, mostly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/qcL9dg79/

Comment: ok, no difference, but i would not rely on that.

Comment: I likely would until the day it came and bit me ;)